# SQL Filter rows based on multiple distinct values of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given the following table

```
DECLARE @YourTable TABLE (id int, PLU int, Siteid int, description varchar(50))

INSERT @YourTable VALUES (1, 8972, 2, 'Beer')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (2, 8972, 3, 'cider')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (3, 8972, 4, 'Beer')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (4, 8973, 2, 'Vodka')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (5, 8973, 3, 'Vodka')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (6, 8973, 4, 'Vodka')
```

I trying to write a query that would give me all rows that have multiple distinct values for a given description value against a plu.

So in the example above I would want to return rows 1,2,3 as they have both a 'cider' value and a 'beer' value for a plu of '8972'.

I thought 'GROUP BY' and 'HAVING' was the way to go but I can't seem to get it to work correctly.

```
SELECT P.PLU, P.Description 
FROM @YourTable P
GROUP BY P.PLU, P.Description
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(P.DESCRIPTION)) > 1
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The question can be worded better, and that would lead to a natural solution.   For example, 'I trying to write a query that would give me all rows that have multiple distinct values for a given description value against a plu.' => 'I am trying to write a query that would give me all rows *for PLU values that have multiple descriptions associated with them*'.  The important thing is that you want to return all rows for a subset of PLU values.  The PLU values you want are ones that have multiple descriptions.  This shows you need to break it up into two steps, ala @Wourter's answer.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat It's often not easy to word an abstract question when you don't know the steps to take to get there. Especially when nursing a slight hangover at the time...

That's why I include the expected results to make it clear what I was after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't `GROUP BY` the description if you are doing a `DISTINCT COUNT` on it (then it will always be just 1).  Try something like this:

```
SELECT P2.PLU, P2.Description
FROM @YourTable P2 
WHERE P2.PLU in (
      SELECT P.PLU 
      FROM @YourTable P
      GROUP BY P.PLU
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(P.DESCRIPTION)) > 1
)
```